# position:relative causing error

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having a page which contains set of buttons at the footer(bottom). When I open the page for the first time I get the buttons as below:

[image]

Now, sometimes the first three buttons gets hidden and I get the page as :
[image]

I am not getting what could go wrong? Interestingly, when I inspect the button and change any property, the buttons get aligned immediately. Strange but true. 
Code for li elements:

```
li
{
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    left: 10px;
    display: block;

    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Now when I remove the position relative then it does not gets hidden but ya, it reaches the top of the page.

Something Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9uk5stfm/)

Update : I assume it is because of `position:relative`, can I change my code without position relative? Or with position:absolute?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uk5stfm/)

Comment: Make a jsfiddle or post html at least.

Comment: That alone is not enough to determine what is going on.  Is your UL in a div?

Comment: @notulysses I am trying to create a fiddle, but it works there.

Comment: @terary Yes. It is inside a div .

Comment: please show your html

Comment: @AhosanKarimAsik I tried, but as I said before. It works fine in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4e8mxehk/.

Comment: @Gun.IO: if example on jsfiddle works as expected, problem has to be elsewhere. Please add link to your page or post to fiddle more of the code, since the problem will be visible there. You probably set other positioning to LIs.

Comment: Looking into it @AhosanKarimAsik. I guess the only change is here `details .action-bottom li `. Right?

Comment: Why not remove the float and set `display:inline-block`?

Comment: not `details .action-bottom li` will be `.details .action-bottom li`

Comment: @Gun.IO in your example you have 2 `position: relative` statements. Is the second one supposed to indicate that you thought it wouldn't have position relative, or do you then comment both of them out?

Comment: Corrected the code. I was pointing to the `position:relative` which is with the class `.details .action-bottom li` in my fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this css:**

```
    .details .action-bottom {
    height: 29px;
    background: #739DDD;
    border: 2px solid #01296E;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
}
.details .action-bottom ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.details .action-bottom li {
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: left !important;
  padding: 6px !important;
  position: inherit;
}
```

[Update Live](http://jsfiddle.net/4e8mxehk/4/)

Comment: Looking into it @AhosanKarimAsik. I guess the only change is here `details .action-bottom li` . Right?

Comment: This did not work. Is it possible to remove `position:relative` and get the same HTML output. I am trying that now. Just referring to [this.](https://alextheedom.wordpress.com/code-and-stuff/creating-buttons-from-ul-element/)

Comment: my be try that. your problem was `left:7px` as defined. so, all `li` get the same position..

Comment: I am doing that at each refresh.

Comment: @Gun.IO see my update.. and check by firebug can have inherited by another css of your project..

Comment: Everything works fine in firefox & chrome. The problem is with stupid IE 7. Grrr...

Comment: It's working. Just needed some minor tweaks for look and feel. +1 and accepted. Thanks.